# How do Clash of Clans and other games rank + match-up their players so effectively?

Tags: database, lua, matching, ranking, roblox

So, a few days ago I worked on a pretty standard ELO system. A player can attack another player's defense, and based on the result, points are redistributed.

It started out working pretty well, but eventually the lower-ranked players could not find match-ups because the way the system finds match-ups is:

- Start at the rank #1 player
- Go down ranks until it finds the player who requested the match-up

Obviously this resulted in having to request data for 2,000 players if the participant's was near rank 2000.

So, now the low-ranked players are finding it impossible to request.

I noticed in other popular titles like Summoners War and Clash of Clans, your ranking is instantly visible whenever your points are adjusted, and I can't possibly imagine them going down the list of every single player until they've reached #200,000.

I'm unable to use the first strategy that came to mind (the number-guessing game), which would be, if there are 100 players, check #50's points. If your points are lower, check #75's, lower: check #88's, etc. This is because I cannot check #50 without also checking #2, #3, etc due to the nature of the OrderedDataStore

I'm trying to store data in such a way that:

- The top 50 players can be displayed
- An algorithm can quickly find 4 defenses of players near your rank
- You can view your own rank

Any solutions?

Comment: (Coming up with an answer as we speak, but for easier searches on your part later "the number-guessing game" is called a binary search, and would normally indeed be what you want to use here)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the top 50 players like so (assuming your ranking list is simply called "ranks":

```lua
ranks.GetSortedAsync(false, 50).GetCurrentPage() -- This will just be an array of the top 50 players.
```

Finding specific players near your rank should be as easy as the following:

```lua
local playerRating -- set this to your player's Elo rating
local searchWidth = 5
ranks.GetSortedAsync(false, 100, playerRating - searchWidth, playerRating + searchWidth)
--[[ the above is a DataStorePages of all players within searchWidth Elo points of your player;
     you may want to widen the search if matches are not found, which is why
     searchWidth is a variable instead of a magic number ]]
```

Getting rank is indeed the hardest part; indeed, I think that the solution might *actually* be along the lines of what you said:

```lua
local playerRating -- set to player's Elo rating
local playerRank = 0
local allRanks = ranks.getSortedAsync(false, 100, playerRating)
while not allRanks.IsFinished do
    allRanks.AdvanceToNextPageAsync()
    playerRank = playerRank + #allRanks.GetCurrentPage()
end
playerRank = playerRank + #allRanks.GetCurrentPage() -- have to add the last page too
```

Due to throttling, it might be best to cache the top 50 in its own data store whenever the store is updated.

You are correct that they're probably not doing a linear search through all of the ranks, but it appears that that's necessary, here.

Comment: This is definitely a great solution and not what I was expecting. the min/max arguments in getsortedasync totally went over my head. What I ended up doing is having multiple ordered datastore keys for players with 100, 200, 300 points etc. I inserted player ranks into those datastores or withdrew them at the end of matches based on ranks. I'll be sure to try this out later.

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, the solution you provided allows me to get a player's rank very quickly. I was completely unaware that feature existed and thought ordered data store had to start at the top/bottom ranks and work its way through.

Comment: Well, I tried getting the rank, but I don't think ordered datastore has any ranking info inside the table it returns.

Comment: I was assuming you had the player's ID as the key and the Elo ranking as a value, as might be expected.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not know what Roblox is capable of for this particular task but requesting 2000 players sounds like a wrong design indeed.

For leaderboards (obviously) you want an ordered list of players sorted by their score. And you need two features:

1. The ability to determine current rank of a player;
2. The ability to query players which rank is in some known interval;

A data structure capable of doing this efficiently is called [Skip List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

And if you want to do it on scale then you need [Redis sorted sets](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/sorted-sets/) which almost everyone is using when you talk about real games.